# Is it possible to create a custom function that does not require parentheses?

Tags: function, hsqldb

I'm trying to mock an Oracle function that doesn't have any parameters for my JUNIT tests. Internally, HSQLDB must have this as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP does not require parentheses.

I want to do something like this:

```
set database sql syntax ORA false;

CREATE SCHEMA DATE_FUNCTION AUTHORIZATION DBA;

CREATE FUNCTION DATE_FUNCTION.HIGH_DATE() RETURNS DATE
LANGUAGE SQL
RETURN DATE '9999-12-31';

set database sql syntax ORA true;

select DATE_FUNCTION.HIGH_DATE from dual;
```

I get this error though:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DATE_FUNCTION.HIGH_DATE
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.checkColumnsResolved(Unknown Source)
```

It works fine with:

```
select DATE_FUNCTION.HIGH_DATE() from dual;
```

This isn't an option for me though as I cannot add parentheses to the original code.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Shaun

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB does not yet support calling functions without adding the parentheses. Future versions may support this for compatibility. You could add Java code to your tests to add the parentheses for specific name patterns that you choose when testing with HSQLDB.